# Codeigniter Upload multiple files different path to database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with my multiple upload with codeigniter,

1. using image
2. another using pdf

When I uploaded the file uploaded twice and how to call different path to uploaded to database. this my code

Controller

```
public function upload(){

    $catalog='catalog';
    $userfile='userfile';

    //for cover
    $config['upload_path'] = './file/book/'; //Use relative or absolute path
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|'; 
    $config['max_size'] = '100000';
    $config['max_width'] = '1024';
    $config['max_height'] = '768';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config); 

    //$c=$this->upload->do_upload($userfile);

    //for catalog
    $config['upload_path'] = './file/book/pdf/'; //Use relative or absolute path
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf'; 
    $config['max_size'] = '1000000';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    //$cat=$this->upload->do_upload($catalog);


    if(!$this->upload->do_upload($catalog) &&         $this->upload->do_upload($userfile)){


        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('uploadds', $error);

    }else{ 



        $this->load->model("book_model"); 
        $this->book_model->addnewbook();
        redirect('book/book');      
    }
```

}

This model

```
function addnewbook(){
     $fcat=array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data($userfile));
     $fcatalog=array('upload_dataa' => $this->upload->data($catalog));
}
```

Comment: A quick google search gave me this. http://pastebin.com/g9J6RxW1. Haven't tried yet. Will try and let you know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to handle multiple uploads independently. For this, you have to create separate **custom objects** for both uploads while loading the upload library. (See the code comments)

```
  public function upload() {

    // Cover upload
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = './file/book/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|';
    $config['max_size'] = '100000';
    $config['max_width'] = '1024';
    $config['max_height'] = '768';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config, 'coverupload'); // Create custom object for cover upload
    $this->coverupload->initialize($config);
    $upload_cover = $this->coverupload->do_upload('cover');

    // Catalog upload
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = './file/book/pdf/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000000';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config, 'catalogupload');  // Create custom object for catalog upload
    $this->catalogupload->initialize($config);
    $upload_catalog = $this->catalogupload->do_upload('catalog');

    // Check uploads success
    if ($upload_cover && $upload_catalog) {

      // Both Upload Success

      // Data of your cover file
      $cover_data = $this->coverupload->data();
      print_r($cover_data);

      // Data of your catalog file
      $catlog_data = $this->catalogupload->data();          
      print_r($catlog_data);
    } else {

      // Error Occured in one of the uploads

      echo 'Cover upload Error : ' . $this->coverupload->display_errors() . '<br/>';
      echo 'Catlog upload Error : ' . $this->catalogupload->display_errors() . '<br/>';
    }
  }
```

Use the data on `$cover_data['full_path']` and `$catlog_data['full_path']` to update your database

Comment: You don't need to load the library multiple times, you can just call initialize on the same library and it will switch the configs out...

Comment: Exactly, perfect. I couldnt find this even in codeigniter docs. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'frontend_assets/images/hospital';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|JPEG||JPG|PNG';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if($_FILES['logo']['name']){
$config['file_name'] = time() . $_FILES["logo"]['name'];

  if (!$this->upload->do_upload('logo')) {

    $this->upload->display_errors();

            } else {

                $upload = $this->upload->data();

                $insert_data['logo'] = $config['upload_path'] . '/' . $upload['file_name'];

            }
            }


if($_FILES['bulding_photo']['name']){
                 $config['file_name'] = time() . $_FILES["bulding_photo"]['name'];

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('bulding_photo')) {

                $this->upload->display_errors());

            } else {

                $upload = $this->upload->data();

                $insert_data['bulding_photo'] = $config['upload_path'] . '/' . $upload['file_name'];
                $this->image_size_fix($insert_data['bulding_photo'], $width = 200, $height = 200);
            }
            }
```